# Calculate dimensions to resize an image

Tags: c#, image-resizing, dimensions

I am creating an image resizer method to fit an image to a maximum size (max-width and max-height). I'm using following method to calculate target dimensions. If width is bigger than max-width, I set the width to max-width and calculate height and then, do this again for height, by using this simple math formulla:

> (width / height) = (maxWidth / maxHeight)

But, resized image seems has not correct dimensions when it got resized. My method is this:

```
private static Size CalculateDimensions(Size currentSize, double maxWidth, double maxHeight) {            
    double width = currentSize.Width,
           height = currentSize.Height;
    if (width > maxWidth) {
        width = maxWidth;
        height = width * maxHeight / maxWidth;
    }
    if (height > maxHeight) {
        height = maxHeight;
        width = height * maxWidth / maxHeight;
    }
    return new Size(Convert.ToInt32(width), Convert.ToInt32(height));   
}
```

Can you tell me where am I wrong? Why this doesn't work?

Comment: Do you really intend to multiply? Can you apply some proper number values and calculate the outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static Size CalculateDimensions(Size currentSize, double maxWidth, double maxHeight) {
    var sourceWidth = (double)currentSize.Width;
    var sourceHeight = (double)currentSize.Height;

    var widthPercent = maxWidth / sourceWidth;
    var heightPercent = maxHeight / sourceHeight;

    var percent = heightPercent < widthPercent
                   ? heightPercent
                   : widthPercent;

    var destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * percent);
    var destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * percent);

    return new Size(destWidth, destHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the ratio of `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` but the ratio of the original `width` and `height`.

What you are currently calculating is the aspect ratio of your maximum sized image which will be a constant and different to the aspect ratio of the original image.

You needs something like the following code:

```
if (width > maxWidth)
{
    double ratio = height / width;
    width = maxWidth;
    height = width * ratio;
}
if (height > maxHeight)
{
    double ratio = width / height;
    height = maxHeight;
    width = height * ratio;
}
```

There are probably other optimisations you can do to the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your max-height and max-width are always proportional to the image dimensions.
Because for your formula to work properly, always current size must be proportional to max size.

Comment: Ya like ChrisF said try to use the image's ratio. That will work.